# CSS -IONIC 2. Display the full value from ion-input or ion-option on screen once selected

Tags: css, angular, ionic-framework, input

I am trying to display the full text from the value picked in an ion-input or ion-option. The problem is that the name of the value is displayed just a half. I would like to put a text-wrap or some css codes that would able to show me the full text from the value selected.

Here I let an image the one displays my problem:

[image]

As you can see, the value Special Acade is not displayed completly, and there are a lot of space to appear.

Code:

```
<ion-item *ngIf="categorySelected " > 
   <ion-label > level 2: </ion-label> 
   <ion-select interface="popover" [(ngModel)]="subCategorySelected" (ngModelChange)="setSubCategorySelected(subCategorySelected)‌​" text-wrap> 
      <ion-option *ngFor="let x of subCategory">{{x.name}}</ion-option> 
   </ion-select> 
</ion-item>
```

How could I solve this?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Please provide your relevant code here..read [mcve]

Comment: Hello @SurajRao, you are right, here I let the code:

Comment: `<ion-item *ngIf="categorySelected " >
      <ion-label >
        level 2:
      </ion-label>
      <ion-select  interface="popover"  [(ngModel)]="subCategorySelected" (ngModelChange)="setSubCategorySelected(subCategorySelected)"  text-wrap>
        <ion-option *ngFor="let x of subCategory">{{x.name}}</ion-option>
      </ion-select>
    </ion-item>`

Comment: I guess that If I could change the width from the ion-label or something like that, the space for the ion-select/input would be better and bigger.

Comment: yes.. you will have to override some css

Answer (score 0):

You can either increase the width of the select text :

```
#myDivId .select-text{
  min-width: 50px;
}
```

Or decrease the space taken by the label

```
#myDivId ion-label{
  max-width: 50px;
}
```